# Can't collapse sections in js files in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I usually use the `CTRL+M CTRL+O` to collapse sections or regions in my `cs` files in Visual Studio 2017. This keyboard shortcut is also working nicely in my `JSX` files. However, it's NOT working in `JS` files.

Interestingly, VS 2017 is able to see and understand functions, even sections within functions such as if blocks, etc. As you can see in image below, it also offers me those +/- icons to collapse them. Using the mouse, I can collapse them but my keyboard shortcut is not working.
[image]

How do I get VS 2017 to collapse everything to definitions in `JS` files using keyboard shortcuts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of this behaviour seems to be the use of the arrow-function - if you change that to a regular function-definition, the section will collapse using `Ctrl+M Ctrl+O` ('Collapse to definitions') like you expect it to.

This will, however, cause you to lose the perks of the [arrow-function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), which is less than optimal, especially when used in conjunction with promises.

What exactly is causing this, however, I haven't been able to discern, and all attempts of fixing it have so far proven futile.

Here's an example of how your outline should work as expected:

```
return function (dispatch) { fetch('/api/accounts/members/search', fetchOptionsPost(request))
    .then(function(response) {
        if(response.ok)
        {
        ...
        }
    });
```

Can anyone confirm whether or not this behaviour occurred in VS2015?

Cheers

Edit 1: `Ctrl+M Ctrl+L` switches all outlines (not just definitions), which seems to include arrow-functions as well. You might have to press it twice, though, because as soon as a single item is collapsed, it expands everything.

Which begs the question whether this is not a bug, but indeed a feature, depending on whether or not you view the arrow-function as a 'definition' or not.

Comment: I really appreciate the detailed response. If this is a feature, it is not a very good one :-) Arrow functions are super useful and when things get busy in a single file, being able to collapse them is very useful too. Microsoft now needs to put the two together. I do need to praise the VS team though for doing a pretty good job improving JSX editing in VS 2017. Sometimes, I find myself surprised how good a job it does.